# Xcode Server: error with -destination flag

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bots, xcode-server

Yesterday I installed the Xcode Server 4.0. I ran a commit on a git repository created on the server and everything was ok. The problem was when I create a bot of the project. As soon as I try to run it an error occurred:

*No destinations were specified with the -destination flag which were valid for the specified scheme 'xxx'*  -> [imagelink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N0kw.png)

Do you know why it happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should ask this question on http://apple.stackexchange.com as this site is for programming questions.

Comment: Xcode Server is a developer tool so I *think* this question is just about on-topic.

Comment: I think like Paul, it's about an error on Xcode not of Apple Server

Comment: Xcode Server 4.0 doesn't exist. It's either Xcode Server 1 (part of Xcode 5) or Xcode Server 2 (part of Xcode 6 Developer Preview.) Which one did you install?

Comment: Ups my fault. It's Xcode Server 2

Comment: There are a number of issues that could cause this. Please execute the following in Terminal: sudo xcrun xcsdiagnose, file a radar to bugreport.apple.com and attach the zip file. Once you're done that, please report back the radar number so I can take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Hi titus, thanks for your help. I installed Beta 2 and the error disappear... but now I have another: "Cancelled integration because headless test environment is required but not available after 60s", sigh :/

Comment: Alleria, please follow my instructions above. There are a few possibilities, and without the diagnostics it's difficult to guess.